# GCE Instance can't by reached by reserved static IP address

Tags: tcp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster with two preemptible instances and one normal instance. I also have a reserved static IP address. I have very liberal firewall rules that basically open tcp:80 and tcp:443 on all nodes from all IP addresses.

If I assign my IP (http://35.226.235.154/) to one of the preemptible instances, I can access port 80 and 443 of the IP address (as expected). However, if I assign the IP to my normal instance, I can't access port 80 or 443. What am I missing?

EDIT:

So i tried to just access it by a normally assigned IP address, and it still does not work, so it seems like my NodePort service is not really working

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're not supposed to assign IPs to nodes manually. If you're trying to use your static IP for an application, see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Comment: So I'm trying to avoid it as an excercise to minimize cost as much as possible. For a single side-project, your load balancer is quite expensive. While I understand that I may be not the typical use case, it still seems to me that what I'm trying to do should work (as the preemptible nodes work just fine)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a service listening on either port 80 or 443 to get a response from the node. You should see the open ports whether the external IP address is static or ephemeral. Normally, the node will host pods which (even if they are exposed on port 80) do not link directly to the node without a service in place ([such as node port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) which does not use a load balancer).

You can also connect to another node to see if the ports are responding using the nodes internal IP address (SSH to node 1, test ports of node 2 using the internal IP address). There is no reason for the external IP address to affect whether a service responds on a port.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a Kubernetes cluster running on all the nodes, with a service as a NodePort, so my understanding is that it will listen on all nodes.

Comment: Do you have a pod on each node? Can you try reaching the internal IP instead of the external to see if you get response?
Normally, the node port service will use ports in an unused range (default: 30000-32767), so to access the pod behind the service, you will target that port.

Comment: I do not have a pod on each node, but my understanding of a NodePort service is that I wouldn't need to. I set the port of the NodePort service, so it should just work, right?

Comment: Not exactly, the NodePort does not bridge nodes together.

NodePort: Exposes the service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort).

This essentially opens a port on the node that links to the service on that node. If there is no service (pod) present on the node, it will not have anything to forward the request to.

Comment: It sounds like to me you are confusing service with a pod?